# Using lxml in Python, I need to replace "RNA" with <mark>RNA</mark> in input xml file. Code below

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

> My **input** XML file is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<try>
something somethingRNA and RNA in RNA.
</try>
```

> My **Python** Code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import openpyxl
import re

url = 'output_15012015_test.xml'

tree = ET.parse(url)

lncrna = "RNA"
abstract = tree.xpath('//try)

string = abstract[0].text

if(abstract):
        anotherString = re.sub(r'\b'+lncrna.lower()+'\\b', '<mark>'+lncrna+'</mark>', string.lower())

abstract[0].text = anotherString
print abstract[0].text
tree.write('FalseRoller.xml', encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True)
```

> **Output**

I get the following replaced text instead of **`<mark>RNA</mark>`**

```
 &lt;mark&gt;RNA&lt;/mark&gt;
```

> I think it has to do with tree.write() method. Also I'm new to Python and the community. Please help me with this.

Comment: I've edited my answer; hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an XML mark in element `.text`, so when writing to XML it is interpreted as text, not markup, and characters are escaped with `&...;`.

What you want to do is:

- divide `.text` into three parts: before new tag, in new tag,
  after new tag
- add new tag and set texts and tails

See code:

```
tree = ET.parse(url)

lncrna = "RNA"
abstract = tree.xpath('//try')

aList = re.split(r'(\b'+lncrna+r'\b)', abstract[0].text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

abstract[0].text = aList[0]
for i in range(1,len(aList),2):
  anElement = ET.SubElement(abstract[0], 'mark')
  anElement.text = aList[i]
  anElement.tail = aList[i+1]
  abstract[0].insert( (i-1)/2, anElement )

print abstract[0].text
tree.write('FalseRoller.xml', encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But I can't understand how ONLY "RNA" is enclosed in <mark> and not the other "re.split" returned strings.

Comment: `i` jumps by 2, i.e. 1, 3, 5,... If pattern in `re.split` is in enclosed in parentheses, then match is placed in result list at these places https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split

Comment: Thank you for the missing piece! It did seem like the logical thing but this is the first time I have come across such a concept. I would vote up your answer once I have enough rep.

Comment: Would this be a prob if the first string returned was "RNA". Something like:
<try>
RNA something somethingRNA and RNA in RNA.
</try>